# Using JavaFX and Gluon, how do you change from loginPage to the MainMenu when the button is clicked?

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I am new to the gluon application. I have used JavaFX and I am building a mobile application. The Login Page worked on its on and now I am trying to configure it to go to the main menu when the button is clicked. I am unsure how to set this up and if you need the init method to be adjusted.

I have tried adding another addViewFactory but that does not work. I tried to create a button with an action but the code fails to load after

This is the main file the application creates

```
public class AlexDemo extends MobileApplication {

@Override
public void init() {

    addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, LoginPage::new);

}

@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);

    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new     Image(AlexDemo.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));

  }
  }
```

This is the Login Page

```
 public class LoginPage extends View {

 private Parent root;

    private LoginPage(BorderPane root) {

    super(root);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 800);

    //For the label displaying "Sign In" to prompt the user
    VBox login = new VBox();
    Label statement = new Label("Sign In");
    statement.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));

    //HBox for the email the user wants to sign in with
    HBox firstUserPrompt = new HBox();
    Label email = new Label("Username/\nEmail: ");
    email.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
    firstUserPrompt.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    TextField userPrompt = new TextField();
    firstUserPrompt.getChildren().addAll(email, userPrompt);

    //HBox for the password the user wants to sign in with
    HBox secondUserPrompt = new HBox();
    Label password = new Label("Password: ");
    password.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));
    secondUserPrompt.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    TextField userPrompt2 = new TextField();
    secondUserPrompt.getChildren().addAll(password, userPrompt2);

    //Sign in Button if the account exists
    Button signIn = new Button("Sign In");
    signIn.setMaxSize(150, 200);
    signIn.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));

  /*   signIn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            MainMenu main = new MainMenu(root, stage);
            scene.setRoot(main); 
            primaryStage.setTitle("Main Menu");
            primaryStage.setWidth(500);
            primaryStage.setHeight(800);

    });*/


    //*** ADD SPACING BETWEEN SIGN IN AND SIGN UP ***

    //If user does not have an account
    VBox newAccount = new VBox();
    Label noAccount = new Label("Don't have an account? Sign up here: ");
    noAccount.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 13));

    Button signUp = new Button("Create Account");
    signUp.setMaxSize(150, 200);
    signUp.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 13));

    newAccount.setSpacing(15);
    newAccount.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    newAccount.setMargin(statement, new Insets(55, 25, 55, 25));
    newAccount.getChildren().addAll(noAccount, signUp);
    root.setBottom(newAccount);

    //makes everything set vertically following one after another
    setCenter(login);
    login.setSpacing(15);
    login.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
    login.setMargin(statement, new Insets(55, 25, 55, 25));
    login.setPadding(new Insets(0, 20, 10, 20)); 
    login.getChildren().addAll(statement, firstUserPrompt, secondUserPrompt, signIn, newAccount);

}

    public LoginPage() {

 this(new BorderPane());

 }

@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {

    appBar.setTitleText("Book App");
    appBar.setSpacing(115);

}

}
```

This is the main menu for now. Have more code here not shown which sets up the main menu

```
public class MainMenu extends View{

private final Parent prevPage;
private final Stage stage;

public MainMenu(Parent LoginPage, Stage stage){

    this.prevPage = LoginPage;
    this.stage = stage;


    Label statement = new Label("Sign In");


}
```

}

When the button is clicked on the login page it should send me to the main menu page

Comment: The application is loading again when I get rid of the Scene scene = new Scene line in the Login Page...how do I set up the button to go to the next page

Comment: There are at least a hundred identical questions like this already answered on Stack Overflow. Try just searching for "login window" or "login page" or "change scenes."

Comment: Sweet man I’ll do more research I couldn’t find any but I never used those key terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters I'd suggest you have a look at the Gluon Mobile [docs](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#_charm_glisten), to see how views work.

Also you should check the many different [samples](https://gluonhq.com/support/samples), that in many cases contain several views, so you can see how to switch from one view to another.

And you should try to use the Gluon [plugin](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/5.0.2/#intellij-plugin) for your IDE, that will create an initial project for you with 2 views.

Now about your issues:

> I have tried adding another addViewFactory but that does not work

That is the way you should use to add as many views as needed.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    addViewFactory(HOME_VIEW, LoginPage::new);
    addViewFactory("MainView", MainView::new);
    ...
}
```

About how you create your views, this is unnecessary:

```
public class LoginPage extends View {
     private Parent root;

     private LoginPage(BorderPane root) {
         super(root);
         Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 800);
         VBox login = new VBox();
         ...
         root.setBottom(newAccount);
         setCenter(login);
         ...
         VBox newAccount = new VBox();
         ...
         root.setBottom(newAccount);
    }

    public LoginPage() {
        this(new BorderPane());
    }
}
```

For starters, `View` [extends](https://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/mvc/View.html) from `BorderPane`, and Gluon Mobile manages the views to get added to the scene, so you shouldn't need a `Scene`.

Your code above can be simplified to:

```
public class LoginPage extends View {

     public LoginPage() {
         VBox login = new VBox();
         ... 
         setCenter(login);
         ...
         VBox newAccount = new VBox();
         ...
         setBottom(newAccount);
     }
}
```

About the `MainMenu` view, it can be simplified as well to:

```
public class MainMenu extends View {

    public MainMenu() {
        Label statement = new Label("Sign In");
        setCenter(statement);
    }
}
```

About switching views, for instance to switch from the home view to the `MainMenu`, you can simply do:

```
Button signIn = new Button("Sign In");
signIn.setOnAction(e -> 
     MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("MainView"));
```

Or if you log out from main menu, you can go back to the home view:

```
Button logOut = new Button("Log Out");
logOut.setOnAction(e -> 
     MobileApplication.getInstance().goHome());
```

Comment: I had gotten rid of the Scene scene = new Scene part and the code worked again just not the button. Ok this makes sense. Where would I initialize MobileApplication?

Comment: You don’t. It is an extension of `Application` class, so that is done automatically

Comment: it is telling me it cannot find the symbol/variable MobileApplication

Comment: I am a dumb ass sorry there is a plugin for it

Comment: You use `MobileApplication` in your main class `AlexDemo`, so you already have the Gluon Mobile dependencies included in your project.

Comment: when I click the button it does not switch to the main menu page

Comment: ahhh it works some minor changes to my code on my end I had to make. Thank you for the help jose I appreciate!